# [Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm running into issues when calling the BedrockClientRuntime in my expo emulator.

Currently, this is how I am calling the client:

```
const client = new BedrockRuntimeClient({
    region: "<region>",
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "<accessKey>",
        secretAccessKey: "<secretKey>",
    },
});
```

And it is resulting in this error: [Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]
when being called by the following:

`const response = await client.send(command);`